# Traversing Graph

Tags: java, graph

I would like to traverse through a Graph and create a duplicate copy of it in my repository. As of now I have used very much boring approach through loops and many counter variable but I'm not happy with that.

The graph looks like following :
![enter image description here][1]

```
    A
 B      C
D  E   F  G
```

My purpose is to traverse through any method (BFS or any other) but ultimate goal to create a duplicate copy of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem?

Comment: You can upload your graph's screenshot to a public file share and edit your question to include the link.

Comment: Is the graph (which is a tree in your example) given via a data structure?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal

Comment: yeah I get JAXB object including all associations.

Comment: @Jeeped, the graph is pretty much like what I described in question, but I will try to upload it.

Answer (score 0):

- Just traverse the graph and create an adjacency matrix and then create a duplicate graph according to the matrix
- You can also use Deep Cloning of the root in order to create a duplicate graph (take advantage of Java Serialization)

Comment: Any reference implementation ? Is it easier to do it through Recursion ?